# Pattern matching and infinite lists

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation, infinite, fold

I'm having trouble understanding this simple snippet of code:

```
-- This works:     foldr go1 [] [1..]
-- This doesn't:   foldr go2 [] [1..]

go1 a b = a : b

go2 a [] = a : []
go2 a b  = a : b
```

Folding with `go1` immediately starts returning values, but `go2` appears to be waiting for the end of the list.

Clearly the pattern matching is causing something to be handled differently. Can someone explain what exactly is going on here?

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answers everyone. If I could select multiple solutions, I would, because they all helped me grok the concept.

Comment: in addition to "selecting" an answer you can also upvote those you deem "helpful" (it says so when you hover above the up arrow). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `go1`, `go2` checks whether or not its second argument is empty. In order to do that the second argument needs to be evaluated, at least enough to determine whether it is empty or not.

So for your call to `foldr` this means the following:

Both `go1` and `go2` are first called with two arguments: 1 and the result of `foldr go [] [2 ..]`. In the case of `go1` the second argument remains untouched, so the result of the `foldr` is simply `1 :: foldr go [] [2 ..]` without evaluating the tail any further until it is accessed.

In the case of `go2` however, `foldr go [] [2 ..]` needs to be evaluated to check whether it is empty. And to do that `foldr go [] [3 ..]` then needs to be evaluated for the same reason. And so on ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1):

To test, whether an expression satisfies some pattern, you need to evaluate it to weak head normal form at least. So pattern-matching forces evaluation.
One common example is the `interleave` function, which interleaves two lists. It could be defined like

```
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave  xs     []    = xs
interleave  []     ys    = ys
interleave (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : interleave xs ys
```

But this function is strict in the second argument. And more lazy version is

```
interleave  []    ys = ys
interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs
```

You can read more here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness

Comment: if it "interleaves two lists", shouldn't it be called `interleave`? "merge" fits better with e.g. mergesort...

Comment: @Will Ness, Fixed. I've seen this function being called "merge" for a several times.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of laziness....  Because of the way that `go1` and `go2` were defined in this example, they will behave exactly the same was for `b==[]`, but the compiler doesn't know this.

For `go1`, the left-most fold will use tail-recursion to immediately output the value of a, and then compute the value of b.

```
go1 a b -> create and return the value of a, then calculate b
```

For `go2`, the compiler doesn't even know which case to match until the value of `b` is computed....  which will never happen.

```
go2 a b -> wait for the value of b, pattern match against it, then output a:b
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the difference try this in GHCi:

```
> head (go1 1 (error "urk!"))
1
> head (go2 1 (error "urk!"))
*** Exception: urk!
```

The issue is that `go2` will evaluate its second argument before returning the head of the list. That is, `go2` is *strict* in its second argument, unlike `go1` which is *lazy*.

This matters when you fold over infinite lists:

```
fold1 go1 [] [1..] =
go1 1 (go1 2 (go1 3 ( ..... =
1 : (go1 2 (go1 3 ( ..... =
1 : 2 : (go1 3 ( ...
```

works fine, but

```
fold1 go1 [] [1..] =
go2 1 (go2 2 (go2 3 ( .....
```

can not be simplified to `1:...` since `go2` insists in evaluating its second argument, which is another call to `go2`, which in turn requires its own second argument to be evaluated, which is another ...

Well, you get the point. The second one will not halt.